# How to create a textbox-like object without plot

Tags: r, text, textbox, formatted

I'm creating some R scripts.  In one of them, I would like to write formatted text enclosed in a box to a png.  I don't know how many lines of text there are, or what the length of the longest line is until I get into the R script, but I want to keep the formatting of the line and have the text fairly tightly enclosed.  When I use a plot and a textbox, the plot comes with a large amount of graphical baggage and undesired behavior.

Is there anything that displays text on the device area that

- does not require a plot,
- wraps lines if they exceed a desired width, and
- tightly surrounds the final text with a box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ggtext::geom_textbox()` in conjunction with `theme_void()`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

txt <- "All human beings are born free and equal in dignity and rights. They are endowed with reason and conscience and should act towards one another in a spirit of brotherhood."

ggplot() +
  geom_textbox(
    aes(x = 0, y = 0, label = txt),
    size = 18 / .pt,
    width = unit(6, "inches")
  ) + 
  theme_void()
```

[image]

You’ll likely need to play with font size, box size, and plot size.

Comment: I'm going to note here that ggtext requires service pack 3.5, unlike ggplot.  I was going to test this on our system before accepting the answer, but our server had an allergic reaction to upgrading from 3.3 to 3.5.  Still, this looks like it's exactly what I need, provided the upgrade can get worked out.

Comment: @user1167758 did u try to install/build the package manually, sometimes that works if its not avail in your version.

Comment: @Ahdee:  If you have experience in this area, I'd be happy to ask a question and pass the answer on.  But our entire team got dumped into a previous team's solution, and all the server guy can tell me is that when he copies the ggtext package over, it doesn't get noticed by SQL server.

Comment: @user1167758 do you have rights to install? if so the eaesiest is this: ```remotes::install_github("wilkelab/ggtext")``` if not then create a local directory and add that directory to your .libpath() and install the package in that directory. Not sure what what it has to do with SQL server since that is a different beast.